# Select different stylesheet according to user in Django template

Tags: python, css, django, django-templates

I want Django (v 1.6) to load a different stylesheet according to the user loading the page. I have tried something like this without success:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Title.</title>
        { % if "{{user.get_username}}" == "user1" %}
            <link href="{% static 'myapp/css/user1_stle.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        { % endif %}
    <head>
    ...
```

Django renders in the source:

```
    <title>Title.</title>
    { % if "user1" == "user1" %}
        <link href="/myapp/css/user1_stle.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    { % endif %}
```

So it loads the stylesheet but not based on the username and I can see the "{ % if ..." section. I think the problem is obvious but I can't see it.

Is there any other way to load a different stylesheet per user? The solution would have to work when I use extends as well.

EDIT: Fixed the space problem but I still don't get the expected behavior. It seems like the strings are not being compared correctly (ifequal not working neither)
Now I'm doing:

```
{% if "{{user.username}}" == "user1" %}
    <script> alert("{{user.username}}");</script>
{% else %}
    <script> alert("{{user.get_username}}" + " different");</script>
{% endif %}
```

And the output is an alert saying user1 different. (same result with get_username and ifequal)

Finally: removed "{{ }}" and worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space between `{` and `%`.  Also change the `if` tag:

```
{% if user.get_username == "user1" %}
    <link href="{% static 'myapp/css/user1_stle.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: you could also use the builtin "ifequal" and "ifnotequal" tags to comparish

Answer (score 1):

Your 'user.get_username' isn't a string but an object that stringifies the result.Instead use, {% if user.get_username|stringformat:"s" == "user1"  %} for correct comparison.

Comment: I didn't know about string format, it might be useful at some point.